# Pad selection range in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I slice a dataframe with something like

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[x] for x in [1,2,3,5,1,3,2,1,1,4,5,6]], columns=['A'])

>>> df.loc[df['A'] == 1]
# or
>>> df[df['A'] == 1]

   A
0  1
4  1
7  1
8  1
```

how could I pad my selections by a buffer of 1 and get the each of the indices `0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`?  I want to select all rows for which the value in column `'A'` is 1, but also a row before or after any such row.

---

**edit** I'm hoping to figure out a solution that works for arbitrary pad sizes, rather than just for a pad size of 1.

---

**edit 2** here's another example illustrating what I'm going for

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[x] for x in [1,2,3,5,3,2,1,1,4,5,6,0,0,3,1,2,4,5]], columns=['A'])
```

and we're looking for `pad == 2`. In this case I'd be trying to fetch rows `0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For arbitrary pad sizes, you may try `where`, `interpolate`, and `notna` to create the mask

```py
n = 2
c = df.where(df['A'] == 1)
m = c.interpolate(limit=n, limit_direction='both').notna()
df[m]

Out[61]:
    A
0   1
1   2
2   3
4   3
5   2
6   1
7   1
8   4
9   5
12  0
13  3
14  1
15  2
16  4
```

Comment: Dang, that's really slick!  Thanks =D

Comment: @RagingRoosevelt: you are welcome. Glad I could help :)

Comment: I played around with this a bit more and it seems like if `filter = df['A'] == 1` then you can simplify even more and just do `c = filter.where(filter)` and then proceed with the interpolation statement to generate the mask.

Answer (score 6):

you can use shift with bitwise or `|`

```
c = df['A'] == 1
df[c|c.shift()|c.shift(-1)]
```

---

```
   A
0  1
1  2
3  5
4  1
5  3
6  2
7  1
8  1
9  4
```

Comment: I saw this and I didn't even try :)

Comment: That's a really slick way to incorporate the shift!  If I wanted a pad larger than 1, though, this wouldn't work anymore, right?

Comment: @RagingRoosevelt I can try, would you be able to provide another example in addition to the one you currently have? :)

Comment: @anky, sure!  say `df = df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[x] for x in [1,2,3,5,3,2,1,1,4,5,6,0,0,3,1,2,4,5]], columns=['A'])` and we're looking for `pad == 2`, then I'd be trying to fetch rows `0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that allows for multiple pad levels.  Use `ffill` and `bfill` on the boolean mask `(df['A'] == 1)`, after converting the `False` values to `np.nan`:

```
import numpy as np

pad = 2
df[(df['A'] == 1).replace(False, np.nan).ffill(limit=pad).bfill(limit=pad).replace(np.nan,False).astype(bool)]
```

Here it is in action:

```
def padsearch(df, column, value, pad):
    return df[(df[column] == value).replace(False, np.nan).ffill(limit=pad).bfill(limit=pad).replace(np.nan,False).astype(bool)]

# your first example
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[x] for x in [1,2,3,5,1,3,2,1,1,4,5,6]], columns=['A'])
print(padsearch(df=df, column='A', value=1, pad=1))

# your other example
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[x] for x in [1,2,3,5,3,2,1,1,4,5,6,0,0,3,1,2,4,5]], columns=['A'])
print(padsearch(df=df, column='A', value=1, pad=2))
```

Result:

```
   A
0  1
1  2
3  5
4  1
5  3
6  2
7  1
8  1
9  4

    A
0   1
1   2
2   3
4   3
5   2
6   1
7   1
8   4
9   5
12  0
13  3
14  1
15  2
16  4
```

Granted the command is far less nice, and its a little clunky to be converting the `False` to and from null.  But it's still using all Pandas builtins, so it is fairly quick still.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution but not nearly as slick as some of the ones already posted.

```py
# setup
df = ...
pad = 2

# determine set of indicies
indices = set(
    [
        x for x in filter(
            lambda x: x>=0, 
            [
                x+y 
                for x in df[df['A'] == 1].index 
                for y in range(-pad, pad+1)
            ]
        )
    ]
)

# fetch rows
df.iloc[[*indices]]
```